# Aplicación de box-shadow en CSS

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

Más allá de las otras diferencias que tiene, no sé cómo imitar esa especie de box-shadow que tiene en el borde inferior la tarjeta. Adjunto imágenes del diseño objetivo y el que yo he planteado.

Adjunto código de mi planteo de la tarjeta:

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Diseño objetivo]

[image: Diseño planteado]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La documentación necesaria la encuentras en [Box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

Hay una caja por detrás;

- offset-x: la mueve horizontalmente
- offset-y: la mueve verticalmente
- blur-radius: hace que el borde se vea borroso gradualmente
- spread-radius: el radio adicional de la caja de atrás

puedes probar en el siguiente snippet:

```css
:root {
    --offset-x: 0px;
    --offset-y: 10px;
    --blur-radius: 15px;
    --spread-radius: 0px;
}
.card {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: var(--offset-x) var(--offset-y) var(--blur-radius) var(--spread-radius) rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 40%;
    
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: -webkit-center;margin-top: 5rem;"><div id="card" class="card">hola</div></div>
offset-x<input id="offset-x" type="range" onchange="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--offset-x', (this.value-50+'px'))"><br>
offset-y<input id="offset-y" type="range" onchange="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--offset-y', (this.value-50+'px'))"><br>
blur-radius<input id="blur-radius" type="range" onchange="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--blur-radius', (this.value+'px'))"><br>
spread-radius<input id="spread-radius" type="range" onchange="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--spread-radius', (this.value+'px'))"><br>
```

En particular el de la imagen que compartes está como 10 pixeles más abajo y el borde un poco borroso, entonces: `box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`